# Error while integrating QnAMAker with Azure Bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, botframeworkemulator

I am trying to integrate QnAMaker with Azure Bot Framework V4.I folllowed the step by step procedure mentioned in Read.me of https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/11.qnamaker

When I run the project and try to chat with the bot in Bot Emulator without mentioning the APPId and APPPassword in the bot emulator,I get the error "[onTurnError] unhandled error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in the project.And the following error in Bot Emulator 'The bot encountered an error or bug'

When I configure the bot emulator with APPID and sand chat with the bot I get the error ""The bot's Microsoft App ID or Microsoft App Password is incorrect."

I don't understand how to fix this issue and make the bot working.

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error in VS Code? Have you double-checked that you are providing the appID and password in the .env file when you enter the values in the Emulator? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435198/qnamaker-sample-the-bots-microsoft-app-id-or-microsoft-app-password-is-incorr

Answer (score 0):

Try putting values for "QnAKnowledgebaseId", "QnAEndpointKey", and "QnAEndpointHostName" in appSettings.json file

Comment: I have done that already.I am getting the above errors after that